# How to set language locale for pandoc citeproc in the command line

Tags: languages, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc, locale

Please let me know to add French to the following argument in the command line, so that strings in English such as *in*, *available at* are translated. The argument `'-V lang=fr-FR'` doesn't change the output.

`pandoc --filter=pandoc-citeproc', '--csl=./files/turabian-fullnote-bibliography.csl', '--bibliography=./files/biblio.bib'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr

Use `-M` instead of `-V`

---

You have to set the language as `metadata` (not as a `variable`).

Let's take the following minimal example:

*biblio.bib:*

```
@inbook{hitchens,
  editor={Christopher Hitchens},
  title={Introduction},
  year={2010},
  author={Sigmund Freud},
  booktitle={Civilization and Its Discontents},
  publisher={W. W. Norton},
  address={New York}
}
```

*in.md:*

```
[@hitchens]

# Bibliography
```

Now you have to run pandoc like this:

```
pandoc in.md --filter=pandoc-citeproc --bibliography=biblio.bib --csl=./turabian-fullnote-bibliography.csl -M lang:fr -o out.pdf
```

Which gives you

*out.pdf:*

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work applied to convert markdown into html in Nikola with Python -this is what I am trying to achieve now.

Comment: Nevertheless, I have reproduced your detailed instructions to convert markdown to pdf with my own data, they do work and are good to know for future use. Thank you.

Comment: I have accepted the answer because it does reply the question I posted. I didn't specify that it is `citeproc-py` that I am using.

Comment: If you are trying to convert markdown to html without any (La)TeX involved, you should ask your question on the pandoc mailing list or [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)